# VBA WebScraping Data Showing Backwards in cell

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am extracting some data from the web everything is coming of fine, except for one set of data, when it is extracted it is showing backwards in the cell.

I can not work out why it is showing backwards, as everything else is extracting fine .

**Q) Could some please advise why it would do this?**

This is is what i am using to pull the data, it works fine for everything else, just not this class it shows backwards in excel

```
        Set doc = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))
        '''IF Statement, change class to suite needs 'bscd
               ' On Error Resume Next
                If doc.getElementsByClassName("bscd")(0) Is Nothing Then
                wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + Counter, 5).Value = "-"
            Else
               ' On Error Resume Next
                wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + Counter, 5).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("bscd")(0).Children(1).InnerText
            End If
```

This is Class

[image: Image of Class]

Result Showing Backwards in excel

[image: Image 2]

Could it be that the "Complete Information" is a JAVA dropdown?

[image: Java Image]

**Just did Ctrl+U as recommended  and this is how the html is, it is showing backwards here, but displays correct on the site**.

[image: image3]

Comment: If the content you could not scrape are static, you should find them in page source (Ctrl + U). Can you share the site url?

Comment: The site is ebay [link] (https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Metal-Floor-Fan-High-velocity-chrome-free-stand-fan-industrial-fan-3-8-Speed-UK/333664038024)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click on that link to access the content. This is one of the ways how you can do. I used Explicit Wait within the script instead of hardcoded delay, so the script will wait up to 10 seconds until the content is visible.

```
Public driver As ChromeDriver

Sub ScrapeContent()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Metal-Floor-Fan-High-velocity-chrome-free-stand-fan-industrial-fan-3-8-Speed-UK/333664038024"
    Dim oElem As Object, oItem As Object
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    driver.get URL

    driver.FindElementByXPath("//span/a[contains(.,'Complete information')]", Timeout:=10000).Click
    Set oElem = driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[contains(.,'Phone:')]/following::span", Timeout:=10000)
    Set oItem = driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[contains(.,'Email:')]/following::span", Timeout:=10000)
    
    Debug.Print oElem.Text, oItem.Text
End Sub
```

Output:

```
13025438495   eshijiali@outlook.com
```

If you use xmlhttp requests, the result you may get is reversed. However, I've used a function to make them regular:

```
Function reverseString(inputStr As String)
    Dim myString$, I&
    
    For I = Len(inputStr) To 1 Step -1
        myString = myString & Mid(inputStr, I, 1)
    Next I
    
    reverseString = myString
End Function

Sub FetchData()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Metal-Floor-Fan-High-velocity-chrome-free-stand-fan-industrial-fan-3-8-Speed-UK/333664038024"
    Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument, oPost As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set oPost = HTML.getElementsByClassName("bsi-lbl")

    If Not oPost Is Nothing And oPost.Length >= 1 Then
        Debug.Print reverseString(oPost(0).NextSibling.innerText)
    End If

    If Not oPost Is Nothing And oPost.Length >= 2 Then
        Debug.Print reverseString(oPost(1).NextSibling.innerText)
    End If
End Sub
```

Output:

```
13025438495   eshijiali@outlook.com
```